# Create Method via GDSL script that has a delegating closure parameter

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

Using the (scarcely documented) gdsl scripts of Intellij, one can add dynamic methods to a class:

```
contributor(context(ctype: "my.Type")) {
  method name: "doIt", params: [body: {}], type: void
}
```

One can also configure the delegation of a closure:

```
contributor(context(scope: closureScope())) {
  def call = enclosingCall("doIt")
  if (call) {
    def method = call.bind()
    def clazz = method?.containingClass
    if (clazz?.qualName == 'my.Type') {
      delegatesTo(findClass('my.Inner'))
    }
  }
}
```

Which, when `doIt` is a method that is defined in the code (not dynamically added), also works as designed.

However, when using the `closureScope` with the previously **created** method, the `containing` class method is always `null`, meaning that I can not safely  delegate inside the closure to the addressed `my.Inner` class.

What I want is adding a dynamic method equivalent to:

```
void doIt(@DelegatesTo(my.Inner) Closure)...
```

I.e. I want the method to be available in code completion (this works), and inside the so created closure, I want correct code completion when addressing methods of `my.Inner`.

So far, I tried various approaches:

- include the @DelegatesTo annotation in the param definition
- try more esoteric approaches in finding the owner of the closure, which fails because the GrMethodCall simply has no parent
- unconditionally delegating all closures named `doIt` to `my.Inner` which works, but is no viable solution since I do have multiple `doIt` methods (on different classes) delegating to different targets.

So, how can I make IDEA behave as expected and delegate to the correct target?

---

**Edit to make it clearer:**

Given the following classes:

```
package my
class Type {
    void doIt(Closure) {}
}
class Inner {
    void inInner() {}
}
```

and the following gdsl:

```
contributor(context(scope: closureScope())) {
  def call = enclosingCall("doIt")
  if (call) {
    def method = call.bind()
    def clazz = method?.containingClass
    println clazz?.qualName
    if (clazz?.qualName == 'my.Type') {
      delegatesTo(findClass('my.Inner'))
    }
  }
}
```

when I start typing in a new script:

```
new Type().doIt {
    inInner()
}
```

When inside the closure, I get the following:

- code completion for `inInner`
- `inInner` is shown as valid
- The console output when started with idea.bat from commandline shows the line `my.Type` (from the `println`)
- Ctrl-B on `inInner` correctly links to source code.

(The same behaviour can be reached without the gdsl when annotation the Closure Parameter in the `doIt` method with `@DelegatesTo(Inner)`)

However, I do not want to manually include the `doIt` method in the source of Type, it is generated by an AST Transformation, so my source file now looks like this:

```
package my
class Type {
}
class Inner {
    void inInner() {}
}
```

I can tell IntelliJ about the new method using the following gdsl snippet

```
contributor(context(ctype: "my.Type")) {
  method name: "doIt", params: [body: {}], type: void
}
```

Now the IDE correctly recognizes the doIt method with a closure parameter. However, inside the Closure, the following happens:

- sometimes code completion shows `inInner`, sometimes after changing something, it does not (when using the original code to fix a type, it was shown, but later declared "unresolved", after going through the code changes of this edited example, it is not shown anymore...)
- Even when shown, `inInner` is shown with "cannot resolve symbol" decoration
- the console shows `null` as `clazz`, i.e. the method is found, but not linked to an owner ASTNode
- Ctrl-B does not link to the corresponding method in `Inner`

So what I want is the same behaviour for an injected `doIt` method (via Gdsl) as with a method included in the source, i.e. I want the gdsl to inject a `doIt` method with a delegating closure (to Inner) into the `type` class.

Comment: The code you posted has syntax errors. Anyways by `previously created methods` do you mean it works for newly added methods ? b/c it is working for me for new class

Comment: Only partially. He actually shows it during code completion but afterwards it is marked as "cannot resolve symbol". I will update the question

Comment: Previously created as opposed to methods present directly in the code.

Comment: I created three tickets around this issue: [IDEA-171017](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171017), [IDEA-171012](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171012) and [IDEA-162019](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162019). However, I am looking for a solution that works with current versions of IntellIj

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me adding the ctype to scope insted of finding the class type from the method

```
contributor(context(scope: closureScope(), ctype: 'my.Type')) {
  def call = enclosingCall("doIt")
  if (call) {
      delegatesTo(findClass('my.Inner'))
   }
}
```

Comment: Same behaviour. Now it appears in code completion again, but is still marked as "cannot resolve"

Comment: you are adding the method definition first right? and could you tell me the intellij version you are using?

Comment: Double checked that: in Intellij 2016.1, it works with ctype, in IntelliJ 2016.2+ it does not work. Seems to match the behaviour of: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162019